# Tkinter: Updating Label with New Background Color (Python 3.5.3)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, timer

I am designing a simple timer using Tkinter that changes color after a certain amount of time has elasped. I have a base timer program which works well, but now I want to modify it so the background changes color.

I have if statements that trigger on the appropriate intervals and then change the class attribute assigned to the background color, but I can't get the label color to update.

I understand the "makeWidgets" function runs only once and believe this is likely the source of my problem. I've experimented breaking out this function into the main program with mixed success. I am able to get the timer to work, but still cannot get the color to change. I have also tried writing a color change function/s but haven't had any success. I am inexperienced with python, tkinter and full-disclosure, I did not design the bulk of the base timer program.

I would really appreciate any direction/advice on how to get this working. I feel that I am either close, or in need of a complete re-work. Hopefully, the former is the case.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

class StopWatch(Frame):
    global mincount
    """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                                
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
    self.start = 0.0        
    self.elapsedtime = 0.0
    self.running = 0
    self.timestr = StringVar()               
    self.makeWidgets()
    self.color = 'green'

def makeWidgets(self):      #this function only run once at setup                   
    """ Make the time label. """
    self.color='green' #this works
    l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr, bg=self.color, font=("Helvetica",300), width=12, height=2)
    self.setTime(self.elapsedtime)
    l.pack(fill=X, expand=YES, pady=2, padx=2)


def update(self): 
    """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
    self.elapsedtime = time.time() - self.start
    self.setTime(self.elapsedtime)
    self.timer = self.after(50, self.update)

def setTime(self, elap,):
    global mincount
    """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
    minutes = int(elap/60)
    seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
    hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)                
    self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))
    mincount = int(elap)
    if mincount>=3:
        print("yellow")
        self.color='yellow' #has no effect
        l.config(bg='yellow') #not in scope
        #CHANGE COLOR TO YELLOW - call fx?
        if mincount>=5:
            print("red")
            #CHANGE COLOR TO RED

def Start(self):                                                     
    """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
    if not self.running:            
        self.start = time.time() - self.elapsedtime
        self.update()
        self.running = 1

def Stop(self):                                    
    """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
    if self.running:
        self.after_cancel(self.timer)            
        self.elapsedtime = time.time() - self.start    
        self.setTime(self.elapsedtime)
        self.running = 0

def Reset(self):
    """ Reset the stopwatch. """
    self.start = time.time()         
    self.elapsedtime = 0.0    
    self.setTime(self.elapsedtime)
    self.color='green'     

def main():
root = Tk()
sw = StopWatch(root)
sw.pack(side=TOP)

Button(root, text='Start', command=sw.Start).pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)
Button(root, text='Stop', command=sw.Stop).pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)
Button(root, text='Reset', command=sw.Reset).pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)
Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)
current=sw.timestr

root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `l` in your `setTime` function : `l` is a local variable in `makeWidgets`
it can't be used in `setTime`. To fix it you have to make `l` a variable part of the class in `makeWidgets` : `self.label = ...` for exemple. And after that use your new variable `self.label` in `setTime` : `self.label.config("bg"="yellow")`

Something can be improved in your if statement `if mincount>=3:` because if it's true you change the bg and after that you check `if mincount>=5`. You should do this:

```
if mincount>=5:
    ...
elif mincount >=3:
    ...
```